# 'language.MatchStrings()' returns garbage

Tags: go, internationalization

I'm having the following piece of code in go:

```
var languageMatcher = language.NewMatcher([]language.Tag{
    language.English, // Default if no match
    language.French,
})

lang, _ := r.Cookie("lang")
accept := r.Header.Get("Accept-Language")

var cookieValue = ""

if cookie != nil {
    cookieValue = lang.String()
}

tag, _ := language.MatchStrings(languageMatcher, cookieValue, accept)

log.Debugf(ctx, fmt.Sprintf("Localized %s to %s. cookie: %s | header: %s", path, tag.String(), cookieValue, accept))

http.Redirect(w, r, "/"+tag.String()+path, 302)
```

Most of it comes from the  [GoDoc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language)

It's working fine most of the time but sometimes (when browsing in private mode from a computer that never visited the website, or when removing the entire cache from the browser (no lang cookie)); the `language.MatchStrings` function returns a bunch of garbage in the tag variable like `en-u-rg-uszzzz`.

Here's the my log.Debugf output:

> `Localized / to en-u-rg-uszzzz. cookie: | header: en-US,en;q=0.9`

Any idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: `display.Self.Name(tag)` may be helpful, see [examples](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language/display#example-Namer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language#NewMatcher), the language matcher may add the Unicode extension on the tag:

> The index returned by the Match method corresponds to the index of the
>   matched tag in t, but is augmented with the Unicode extension ('u')of
>   the corresponding preferred tag. This allows user locale options to be
>   passed transparently.

This explains the weird `en-u-rg-uszzzz` value. As the matcher provides us the index of the matched language in the array, a workaround would be to use it to retrieve the original language:

```
var availableLanguages = []language.Tag{
    language.English, // Default if no match
    language.French,
}
var languageMatcher = language.NewMatcher(availableLanguages)

lang, _ := r.Cookie("lang")
accept := r.Header.Get("Accept-Language")

var cookieValue = ""

if lang != nil { // Be careful: the variable name was wrong
    cookieValue = lang.String()
}

_, i := language.MatchStrings(languageMatcher, cookieValue, accept)

log.Debugf(ctx, fmt.Sprintf("Localized %s to %s. cookie: %s | header: %s", path, availableLanguages[i].String(), cookieValue, accept))

http.Redirect(w, r, "/"+availableLanguages[i].String()+path, 302)
```

A bit hacky, but it works.

Regards!